# Static data with Amazon Alexa?

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a skill (using node.js) in which the user asks Alexa for a city and she responds with their three major sports teams. For example:

User: "Alexa, what are Cleveland's sports teams?"
Alexa: "Cleveland has the Cavaliers, the Browns, and the Indians."

Since the size of this data is unchanging, do I try and convert a .csv or .xlsx file to JSON or do I try and populate a dynamoDB table? Or is there a better way to do this that I am unaware of?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may incur charges if you use DynamoDB (I've been having to pay for my skills but recently Amazon is providing credits for skill developers) and, as you said, it's static data and probably fits nicely in a JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data doesn't change very often, it probably makes sense to just create a table within the Lambda. I'd suggest using a built-in city slot such as AMAZON.US_CITY, then use the slot value to index into your table.

You might also consider allowing the user to specify the specific sport using the AMAZON.Sport slot also. Another option would be to allow the opposite question, such as "In what city do the {AMAZON.SportsTeam} play?" I'm not much into sports, so I'd probably use this skill myself. I hope you get it published.

Side note: Alexa already provides some support for this. For example, you can already ask "Alexa, what teams are in Los Angeles" and it responds with "The teams that are in Los Angeles are Lakers and Dodgers". But it doesn't know how to answer other related questions such as the one above.

This sounds like fun. Good luck with it.

Comment: This has been really helpful. Thank you for your response!